# Need to define an alias for a DataMapper property

Tags: properties, sinatra, alias, datamapper, padrino

I am working on a Padrino/Sinatra app that is using the jQuery UI Autocomplete in a certain section.

To populate the autocomplete, I have defined the following:

```
get '/autocompletedata' do
  content_type :json
  Foo.all.to_json(:only => :name)
end
```

This returns the property `name` from model `Foo` in a nice JSON array, as thus:

```
[{"name":"First"},{"name":"Second"},{"name":"Third"},{"name":"Fourth"}]
```

However, jQuery's Autocomplete requires that the name of the attribute in the returned JSON packet is labelled as `label`, as thus:

```
[{"label":"First"},{"label":"Second"},{"label":"Third"},{"label":"Fourth"}]
```

Is there a quick and programmatic way to change the name of the property from `name` to `label` here during the conversion process?

Failing that, can we define alias properties in DataMapper?  I cannot seem to find a way to do that either?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out a workaround for this.

In my model `Foo`, I added the following method:

```
def label
  name
end
```

And then I changed the `to_json` options as thus:

```
Foo.all.to_json(:methods => :label)
```

and got the results I wanted.  Actually, to make things work even more smoothly, I ended up narrowing down the DataMapper query some more:

```
Foo.all(:fields => [:name]).to_json(:methods => :label, :only => :label)
```